# For Loop clarification

Tags: procedural-programming

I have the following dataset:

```
plgs = {{{1522., 388.5}, {1543.18, 414.971}, {1522., 406.5}}, {{1508.5, 
421.5}, {1508.5, 400.528}, {1515.69, 404.923}, {1511.83, 
416.5}}, {{565.455, 408.545}, {576.778, 397.222}, {594., 
426.5}, {614.375, 467.25}}, {{559.605, 386.053}, {548.065, 
416.826}, {213.929, 667.429}, {538.434, 363.636}}, {{1503.8, 
392.6}, {1502.82, 395.128}, {1369.24, 389.057}, {1491.38, 
347.071}}, {{1560.31, 482.308}, {1603.53, 445.263}, {1621.91, 
433.98}, {1715.11, 637.109}}, {{1097.69, 735.5}, {1091.99, 
283.009}, {1145.27, 324.965}, {1284.22, 735.5}}, {{246.529, 
735.5}, {648.257, 525.978}, {814.646, 461.982}, {821.031, 
735.5}}, {{821.031, 735.5}, {814.646, 461.982}, {889.082, 
353.262}, {928.152, 300.524}, {971.65, 735.5}}, {{1502.82, 
395.128}, {1503.35, 396.805}, {1434.43, 560.485}, {1281.53, 
410.475}, {1369.24, 389.057}}, {{1503.35, 396.805}, {1508.5, 
400.528}, {1508.5, 421.5}, {1437.37, 563.76}, {1434.43, 
560.485}}, {{1543.18, 414.971}, {1546., 416.5}, {1511.83, 
416.5}, {1515.69, 404.923}, {1522., 406.5}}, {{577.11, 
395.394}, {591., 393.5}, {594., 393.5}, {594., 426.5}, {576.778, 
397.222}}, {{576.682, 394.591}, {559.605, 386.053}, {538.434, 
363.636}, {544.174, 351.773}, {587.882, 338.591}}, {{577.11, 
395.394}, {576.682, 394.591}, {587.882, 338.591}, {591., 
336.776}, {591., 393.5}}, {{1484.16, 735.5}, {1446.59, 
574.589}, {1560.31, 482.308}, {1715.11, 637.109}, {1762.07, 
735.5}}, {{758.94, 231.5}, {591., 336.776}, {587.882, 
338.591}, {544.174, 351.773}, {451.872, 231.5}}, {{1646., 
231.5}, {1520., 384.5}, {1503.8, 392.6}, {1491.38, 
347.071}, {1643.73, 231.5}}, {{1762.07, 735.5}, {1715.11, 
637.109}, {1621.91, 433.98}, {1745.26, 231.5}, {2001.25, 
231.5}, {2001.25, 735.5}}, {{594., 426.5}, {594., 393.5}, {889.082,
353.262}, {814.646, 461.982}, {648.257, 525.978}, {614.375, 
467.25}}, {{971.65, 735.5}, {928.152, 300.524}, {974.766, 
231.5}, {1058.03, 231.5}, {1091.99, 283.009}, {1097.69, 
735.5}}, {{576.682, 394.591}, {577.11, 395.394}, {576.778, 
397.222}, {565.455, 408.545}, {548.065, 416.826}, {559.605, 
386.053}}, {{451.872, 231.5}, {544.174, 351.773}, {538.434, 
363.636}, {213.929, 667.429}, {208.75, 671.951}, {208.75, 
231.5}}, {{1284.22, 735.5}, {1145.27, 324.965}, {1281.53, 
410.475}, {1434.43, 560.485}, {1437.37, 563.76}, {1446.59, 
574.589}, {1484.16, 735.5}}, {{974.766, 231.5}, {928.152, 
300.524}, {889.082, 353.262}, {594., 393.5}, {591., 393.5}, {591., 
336.776}, {758.94, 231.5}}, {{1603.53, 445.263}, {1560.31, 
482.308}, {1446.59, 574.589}, {1437.37, 563.76}, {1508.5, 
421.5}, {1511.83, 416.5}, {1546., 416.5}}, {{1643.73, 
231.5}, {1491.38, 347.071}, {1369.24, 389.057}, {1281.53, 
410.475}, {1145.27, 324.965}, {1091.99, 283.009}, {1058.03, 
231.5}}, {{208.75, 735.5}, {208.75, 671.951}, {213.929, 
667.429}, {548.065, 416.826}, {565.455, 408.545}, {614.375, 
467.25}, {648.257, 525.978}, {246.529, 735.5}}, {{1520., 
384.5}, {1522., 388.5}, {1522., 406.5}, {1515.69, 
404.923}, {1508.5, 400.528}, {1503.35, 396.805}, {1502.82, 
395.128}, {1503.8, 392.6}}, {{1745.26, 231.5}, {1621.91, 
433.98}, {1603.53, 445.263}, {1546., 416.5}, {1543.18, 
414.971}, {1522., 388.5}, {1520., 384.5}, {1646., 231.5}}}
```

Now, I want to make a for loop that can find the adjacent neighbor for last three polygon values. Here is the following code I tried for finding neighbor of the last three polygon. But, it gives error. How can I run the for loop?

```
For[i = 1, i < sv + 1, i++, 
  iLength = Length[plgs[[-i]]]
  neigh[[i]] = 
    Select[
      plgs[[;; -i - 1]], 
      Length[Union[Join[#, plgs[[-i]]]]] =!= Length[#] + iLength &]]
  aa = neigh[[1]]
```

Comment: You have some basic syntax issues.  Read this post [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393). In particular the body of he `For` is taking the results of each line and multiplying them together. You need to use the terminating semicolon.

Comment: I can not comprehend your question. What do you  mean by "adjacent neighbor" and "last three polygons"? Also, why are using a for-loop at all, when only want to compute `neigh[[1]]`?

Comment: Please fix the basic syntax issues that  Edmund describes, then see if you have further problems and update the question if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You have several post leading up to this one and it appears that you have been working up to this for a couple of days. Please read [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393).  This will really help you out as *Wolfram Language* is different most traditional programming languages.

You don't need a loop to code this the *Wolfram Language* way.

Taking *adjacent* to mean that a polygon shares a vertex with the central polygon then an example of how to code this and display this is.

```
Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Black], Polygon@plgs,
  LightGray, Polygon@ 
   Flatten[Through[(Select /@ Thread@ContainsAny[plgs[[-3 ;;]]])[plgs[[;; -4]]]], 1],
  Blue, Polygon@plgs[[-3 ;;]]}]
```

[image]

Have a read of how each of the functions work in the documentation. `Map` (`\@`) and `Span` (`;;`) are particularly useful. These and a few others pretty much negate the need for loops in most cases.

Hope this helps.